# Is the number of layers in the google inception net really 22?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i counted the number of conv layers and they are more than 22?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually people only count layers that have weights, in this case convolution layers only, also parallel convolutions count as the same layer.
Pooling, softmax and concat/normalize are thought of as being part of the preceding layer.

Comment: what about the conv and FC layers in the additional loss branches ? Do we count them? if don't, then why?

Comment: Normally you would count all FC and convolutional layers, but I believe in this case the ones in the extra loss branches are seen as an extra thing in parallel. The number of layers of a network can be somewhat subjective, in this case it appears to refer to the maximum depth of the main network (I counted 22 this way at least)